# Как подключить библиотеку

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу подключить [эту](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt) библиотеку, но не знаю как... Поискал в инете, но везде указывают путь до .lib, которого тут нет.
Вот что пытался сделать, но это очевидно не верно:
Test.pro

```
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION = $$PWD/../../../build/SMTPEmail-Desktop-Debug

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION/release/ -lSMTPMime
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION/debug/ -lSMTPMime
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION -lSmtpMime

INCLUDEPATH += $$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION
DEPENDPATH += $$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION
```

Вот что выводиться

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/build-Test-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\Test.exe debug/main.o  -LD:....\build\SMTPEmail-Desktop-Debug\debug -lSMTPMime D:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\lib\libQt6Gui.a D:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\lib\libQt6Core.a
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSMTPMime
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:68: debug/Test.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/build-Test-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: debug] Error 2
16:05:57: Процесс «D:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта Test (комплект: Desktop Qt 6.2.0 MinGW 64-bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»

:-1: ошибка: cannot find -lSMTPMime
:-1: ошибка: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Добавил вывод к вопросу

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что вы имели ввиду, пытался исправить `D:....\`, теперь так
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/build-Test-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\Test.exe debug/main.o  -L D:\Test\src -lSmtpMime D:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\lib\libQt6Gui.a D:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\lib\libQt6Core.a   
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSmtpMime

Comment: Вы библиотеку собрали?

Comment: Видимо в этом и проблема. Не подскажите или дадите ссылку на то, как собрать библиотеку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Откройте SmtpClient-for-Qt в Qt Creator и забилдите проект.
2. Вставьте в .pro файл своего проекта следующий код:

   SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION = $$PWD/../../../build/SMTPEmail-Desktop-Debug

   win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION/release/ -lSMTPMime
   else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION/debug/ -lSMTPMime
   else:unix: LIBS += -L$$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION -lSmtpMime

   INCLUDEPATH += $$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION
   DEPENDPATH += $$SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION

где, SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION - путь к папке с билдом